# how to align the legend title to the middle of legend box in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to move the legend title `sex` a little right to the horizontal center of legend box. I tried `theme` and `guide_legend` but failed. Both ways won't change the legend title position.

```
# example data from http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/
df1 <- data.frame(
    sex = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
    time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner","Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
    total_bill = c(13.53, 16.81, 16.24, 17.42)
)

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, group=sex, shape=sex, colour=sex)) +
    geom_line() + geom_point()

# no change
p + theme(legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
p + guides(color=guide_legend(title.hjust=0.5))
```

In addition, I am using ggplot2_2.2.0.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need `legend.title.align` rather than `legend.title`:

```
p + theme(legend.title.align=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work for [long legend titles.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48000292/center-align-legend-title-and-legend-keys-in-ggplot2-for-long-legend-titles)

Comment: @ClausWilke it works well for long titles if you break it with a newline: `"\n"`